# Add a number in a column via sql

Tags: sql, database

I have a column with a week number. Instead of week number starting from the start of the year, I want to add `53` to each week

e.g. 2nd week of Jan will be Week 2 but I want to display it as `Week 55 (53+2).`

```
select week(cs.subscribeddate)+53 as sub_week
from Test
where 1
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: SQL-Server or mysql or postgresql? please remove incompatible tags

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Postgresql? (You'll have different answers for each one...)

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using? Tag only relevent

Comment: What is the Output you get?

Comment: What is the error message? And are you sure it should be cs.subscribeddate and not just subscribeddate? If you give us the error message it will be easier to solve.

Comment: Alias `cs` is not defined.

Comment: What is `cs`?. And `where 1` is not neccessary. Remove it

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server then use  below solution

```
select DATEPART (week , getdate())   +53  as sub_week
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
select week(cs.subscribeddate)+53 as sub_week
from Test
where 1
```

In the above you are fetching ur column with table alias but no alias is defined in the above query. Also in SQL Server, use `DatePart` Please do the following to get it work:

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, cs.subscribeddate) + 53 as sub_week
FROM Test cs
```

Without alias, the query would be:

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, subscribeddate) + 53 as sub_week
FROM Test
```